# Error in java code

Tags: java, eclipse

i am new to java programming . i was coding a program to no read data from a file. 
so this is the code
iwas getting error in line 13 is at rtwm.Input.(Input.java:13)
and error in line 37 is  rtwm.Input.main(Input.java:37)

CODE written below

```
package rtwm;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;

public class Input {


          private FileInputStream in;

          public Input(String filename) throws FileNotFoundException {

            in = new FileInputStream(filename);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public String getWord() throws IOException {
        int c;
        StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

        do {
          c = in.read();
          if (Character.isSpace((char) c))
            return buf.toString();
          else
            buf.append((char) c);
        } while (c != -1);

        return buf.toString();
      }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.io.IOException {
        Input file = new Input("source.txt");
        System.out.println(file.getWord());
        System.out.println(file.getWord());
        System.out.println(file.getWord());
      }
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Can u please find the error 
thank you

Comment: Could you please describe what error you're getting?

Comment: error in line 13 - at rtwm.Input.(Input.java:13) and error in line 37 is rtwm.Input.main(Input.java:37)

Comment: error in line 13 is at rtwm.Input.(Input.java:13) and error in line 37 is rtwm.Input.main(Input.java:37)

Comment: @NikhilChitale: Yes, we can see _where_ the error is since you've stated that in your post already but _what_ error are you getting? With the information you've given us so far I can only assume it's a FileNotFoundException.

Comment: @WhoAmI asking you what are the errors not at which lines you are getting the errors

Comment: error is in the 'package rtwm' please check or provide that code

Comment: at rtwn.Input.<Init>(Input.java:13)

Comment: If you get any exception in line no:13 means May be i.e is `FileNotFoundException` 
Are you getting this one ?

Comment: have a look at the first line of the code provided by the OP

Comment: ya package is included no doubt about it sir.

Comment: when I am compiling it its working fine...

Comment: Can you just copy/paste the whole text of the error you're getting? not just 'at rtwm.Input'

Comment: Are you using any IDE?

Answer (score 2):

After running and investing the code many times, the only error possible for **this** code:

**FileNotFoundException** that may occur if the (relative) file path "source.txt" is not correctly set to the path, so to make sure try an absolute path and then run your code. (You can use relative paths but if you use it properly)

---

Sample test result :

file input :

```
abcd 123 efg 456
lmn 567 llll kjmn
```

result:

```
abcd
123
efg
```

Comment: ya.. Its FNF. I don't see anything else here

Comment: @WhoAmI> Exactly, I could run the program with an arbitrary text file with a right file path, and now represented the result.